# Athena query timeout for bucket containing too many log entries

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am running a simple Athena query as in

```
SELECT * FROM "logs"
WHERE parse_datetime(requestdatetime,'dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z')
BETWEEN parse_datetime('2021-12-01:00:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss')
AND
parse_datetime('2021-12-21:19:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss');
```

However this times out due to the default DML 30 min timeout.

The entries of the path I am querying are a few millions.

Is there a way to address this in `Athena` or is there a better suited alternative for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

This is normally solved with [partitioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html). For data that's organized by date, [partition projection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html) is the way to go (versus an explicit partition list that's updated manually or via Glue crawler).

That, of course, assumes that your data is organized by the partition (eg, `s3://mybucket/2021/12/21/xxx.csv`). If not, then I recommend changing your ingest process as a first step.

You my want to change your ingest process anyway: Athena isn't very good at dealing with a large number of small files. While the [tuning guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/performance-tuning.html#performance-tuning-data-size) doesn't give an optimal filesize, I recommend at least a few tens of megabytes. If you're getting a steady stream of small files, use a scheduled Lambda to combine them into a single file. If you're using Firehose to aggregate files, increase the buffer sizes / time limits.

And while you're doing that, consider moving to a columnar format such as Parquet if you're not already using it.